# Scheduled backup of certain directories in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backup, 7-zip, windows-task-scheduler

I'm using Windows 7 and I need to schedule a daily backup that does the following:

- The schedule needs to run daily at 7pm
- The backup needs to generate a compressed archive of selected backup directories. These archives are ideally created with 7zip.
- The archives generated by the backup need to be placed in a directory on my filesystem of my choosing.

I know Python and MSBatch, but I was hoping I wouldn't have to write a script for this. Are there any tools out there that will do what I need or at least something similar? I can use the Windows 7 task scheduler to execute this, but I don't know of what program it would execute.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the 7zip command line tool and the windows task scheduler.

Download the 7zip command line tool from http://www.7-zip.org/download.html and extract it to c:\7zip

Open notepad and create a list of the directories you want to backup, one path per line

```
c:\users\username\important directory1
c:\users\username\important directory2
```

Go to tools->save and make sure to change the drop down menu from ANSI to UTF-8 and save the file as c:\users\username\backuplist.txt

Now, open the windows task scheduler and create a new task. Give the task a name and select to run it daily at your specified time. Select that you want to run a program and fill in the fields as follows

```
Program: c:\7zip\7za.exe
Arguments: a c:\backups\backupname.7z -r @c:\users\username\backuplist.txt
run in: c:\7zip
```

Now save the task and you should have a working backup solution based on 7zip.

Comment: How can the date+time be added to the filename ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a backup service. You are probably best off just using the wizard provided, need for anything fancy. (type backup into the start box).

Comment: I don't think that Backup and Restore in windows creates ZIP archives. This won't work for me as that means Windows is required to extract my backups.

Comment: According to [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/how-do-i-manually-extract-files-from-file-backup/97e2ecde-fe58-44e1-a70b-5927461271a4) if its large its multiple zips. Leads me to believe that small is one zip

Comment: Also according to wikipedia backup type (except for full drive) is zip. see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_and_Restore)

Answer (score 1):

If you open your start menu, go to the **Control Panel > Backup and Restore.** Clicking it will bring up this:

[image: backup and restore]

From there you can schedule backups to the selected location you want. Just hit **Setup a backup**

It should look like this once you complete the steps:

[image: finished backup]

I am still investigating the zip part of this.